# remove specific data within the string in R

Tags: r, dataframe, summarize

im new to R, i have this data frame and im trying to delet all the infromation from this column except the genes symbols which always comes secound in place within the string.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsqY4.png)
best regards!

i tried this function (gsub) but it deleted the specific element only . i`m wandring if i can use it to keep the gene symbol only ( which is always come in the secound place in the string) and delet every thing else

Comment: Please do share your `gsub()` attempt, if you were able to delete that specific (correct, I assume) element, you just need to fiddle with groups a bit to only keep that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is consistently in the format shown in the image (where the gene ID is always the third "word" of the string), then the `word()` function from the **stringr** package can extract the data you want.

```r
library(stringr)

dat = data.frame(gene_assignment = rep(c('idnumbers // geneID // Other stuff'),10))

dat$geneID = word(dat$gene_assignment, 3)
```

Note that this makes the following assumptions:

1. Your data is always in the format where there are some id numbers, followed by " // ", followed by the gene ID, followed by a space, and then anything else
2. Neither the ID numbers in the front nor the gene ID ever contain a space in them

These assumptions are necessary because `word()` uses spaces to determine when each word starts and ends.

Comment: If those assumptions *are* violated, by the way, then you'll have to stitch together some stringr stuff using str_locate and str_sub to (1) str_locate to find the position of the first // in each row, (2) str_sub to the spot right after that location you found, overwriting the original string, (3) repeat step 1 on the new string, (4) str_sub to cut off everything from the // onwards, (5) str_trim to get rid of whitespace

Comment: thanks! this code just worked perfectly dat$geneID = word(dat$gene_assignment, 3)

Comment: Great! Feel free to mark this answer as Correct so that anyone else coming along will know it works.